# Migrate Cloud Compute VM to Separate Google Cloud Account

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Just curious if there's a standard method to take one VM instance and migrate it to a completely different Google Cloud account. If not, I guess I could download all the site files and server configuration files (virtual hosts, apache config, php.ini, etc) but am hoping there's a more streamlined approach.

Just to be clear I have john@gmail.com and john2@gmail.com, both completely separate accounts each with VMs on their respective Google Cloud accounts. I want to move a VM instance from john@gmail.com to john2@gmail.com

I'm open to any method that will get the job done. I like Google's snapshot feature but I have doubts I'll be able to move the specific snapshot over. I'm thinking maybe it'll be possible by creating an image but even that I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

[Create a custom image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image), then share it, then [import that image](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/creating-custom-image#importing_an_image) into the target project.

Comment: Will image contain all the HD content (Exact copy of the computer) or just the configuration of the computer? Thank You.

Comment: @Royi you’re creating an image of the boot disk. Whatever is on that disk at the time you make the request is captured. If you have attached persistent disks then you may need to take snapshots of those too. For consistency across disks, it’s better to flush all disk writes and stop the instance first.